# Codeigniter URL parametres using modal contact

Tags: jquery, codeigniter-2, modal-dialog, simplemodal

I'm using Modal contact from from http://www.ericmmartin.com/simplemodal-1-4-4-released/
and Codeigniter as PHP framework.

It's work greate if my URL is

http://site.com/controler/function (vithout slash / at the end of URL)

but if i add slash (/) to the end http://site.com/controler/function/

or other parameters http://site.com/controler/function/parameters....

i have an error like this (**NS_ERROR_XPC_BAD_CONVERT_JS: Could not convert JavaScript argument arg 0 [nsIDOMWindow.getComputedStyle]**)

In my view i use:

```
<div id="contact-form" class="button center">
           <a href="#" target="_self" class="contact">
                   Contact Form
           </a>
</div>
```

Please, give me any suggestions, or how can i resolve this issue!

Answer (score 0):

I solve this with config/routes.php

Was same mistakes from my side.